# Marionette table tr rowspan render

Tags: backbone.js, haml, marionette

How can I use ItemView or CollectionView to render html like below:

```
  %table
      %tr
        %td{:rowspan=>"3"} Name1
        %td{:rowspan=>"3"} Time1
        %td Step1
      %tr
        %td Step2
      %tr
        %td Step3
      %tr
        %td{:rowspan=>"2"} Name2
        %td{:rowspan=>"2"} Time2
        %td Step4
      %tr
        %td Step5
```

My json like this:

```
{
    Name: 'Name1',
    Time: 'Time1',
    Log:
    [
        {
            Step: 'Step1',
        },
        {
            Step: 'Step2',
        },
        {
            Step: 'Step3',
        },
    ]
},
{
    Name: 'Name2',
    Time: 'Time2',
    Log:
    [
        {
            Step: 'Step4',
        },
        {
            Step: 'Step5',
        },
    ]
},
```

I just start to learn marionette recently. I not sure how to deal with this problem. Could anyone give a help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but when serializing or when using this to render, you can output the value of logs.length, to determine the rowspan.

In plain HTML, something like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td rowspan=<%= logs.length %>"><%= name %></td>
<td rowspan=<%= logs.length %>"><%= name %></td>
<etc>
</tr>
</table>
```

Shouldn't that work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want each name+time+log+step thing as an item and the table as a collection:

```
var ItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#foo',
    tagName: 'tr'
});

var CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: Item,
    tagName: 'table'
});

var data = []; // your JSON
var collection = new Backbone.Collection(data);
var collectionView = new CollectionView({ collection: collection });

// container = document.body or whatever
container.append(collectionView.render().el);
```

Now for your template, I don't believe underscore templates (which is what Backbone and therefore Marionette uses) plays well with HAML. But using just `erb` syntax, your template would be something like:

```
<script type="text/template" id="foo">

<!-- format however you want -->

<td><%- Name %></td>
<td><%- Time %></td>
<td>
    <ul>        
    <% _.each(Log, function(li){ %>
        <li><%- li.Step %></li>
    <% }); %>
    </ul>     
</td>

</script>
```